# Mocking functions within Go package functions

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I am trying to mock an HTTP client that's being used within an API function call in my Go code.

```
import (
    "internal.repo/[...]/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func CreateResource(t *testing.T, url string, bodyReq interface{}, username string, password string, resource string) []byte {
    bodyReqJSON, err := json.Marshal(bodyReq)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    headers := make(map[string]string)
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

    logger.Logf(t, "*************************** CREATE a temporary test %s ***************************", resource)

    // this func below should be mocked
    statusCode, body := http.POST(t, url, bodyReqJSON, headers, username, password)

    require.Equal(t, statusCode, 201, "******ERROR!! A problem occurred while creating %s. Body: %s******", resource, strings.TrimSpace(string(body)))

    return body
}
```

I'd like to mock my `http.POST` function that it's part of an internal HTTP package so that I do not need to actually make the online call, and isolate the test offline.

Is there an alternative way to dependency-inject a mock structure that implements an hypothetical HTTP interface?

How would you do something like this?

Comment: Consider using [httptest.Server](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server) and [httptest.ResponseRecorder](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder).

Comment: So the solution is, instead of mocking the `http.POST`, to mock the HTTP server URL?

Comment: The solution is to not mock anything. Just use a real (local) server. Perhaps you mean "inject" instead of "mock". In that case, yes, inject either the test server's base url or its [client](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server.Client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution, thanks to @Peter.

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestCreateResource(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("successful", func(t *testing.T) {
        server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            w.WriteHeader(201)
        }))
        defer server.Close()

        o := CreateResource(t, server.URL, nil, "admin", "password", "resource")
        assert.Equal(t, []byte{}, o)
    })
}
```